# Calculate the expression of divergence in spherical coordinates $r, \theta, \varphi$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, differentiation, vector-fields

Hi this is my first question in [Physics.SE] I saw a lot of posts and I liked them. I hope that my question will be answered too.

While I'm solving a problem in vector calculus. I recognized that I need a proof to answer it.

> The problem is the following: Calculate the expression of divergence in spherical coordinates $r, \theta, \varphi$ for a vector field $\boldsymbol{A}$ such that its contravariant components $A^i$

Here's my attempts:

We know that the divergence of a vector field is :
$$\mathbf{div\ V}=\nabla_i v^i$$
Notice that $\mathbf{V}$ is the vector field and $\nabla_k v^i$ its covariant derivative, contracting it we obtain the scalar $\nabla_i v^i$.

My questions are how I can apply this to solve the main problem ?

Can I use the developed expression of the covariant derivative? which is : $$\nabla_k v^i=\partial_k v^i+v^j\Gamma_{kj}^i$$

Comment: You gave the answer of your first question by the second one, I mean use that expression to solve your problem by taking $x^1=r , x^2=\theta , x^2=\varphi $

Comment: Yes, you can just use the covariant derivative as you say. You just need the Christoffel symbols in spherical coordinates. Which is just worked out from the metric (minkowski space for your problem)

Comment: @SamuraiMelon Well this is the main problem !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

and welcome to [Physics.SE], I tried to solve your problem and here is what I found:

As you said the divergence can be written :
$$\mathbf{div \ V}=\nabla_i v^i$$
And the expression of the covariant derivative is :
$$\nabla_k v^i=\partial_k v^i+v^j\Gamma_{kj}^i$$
Using it we obtain :
$$\mathbf{div \ V}=\partial_i v^i +v^j\Gamma_{ij}^i$$
Using Ricci theorem :
$$\nabla_k g_{ij}=\partial_kg_{ij}-\Gamma_{ik}^l g_{lj}-\Gamma_{jk}^l g_{il}=0$$
Multiplying by $g^{ij}$ :

> Recall: $g^{ij}g_{jl}=\delta_i^l$

$$g^{ij}\partial_k g_{ij}-\Gamma_{ik}^l \delta_i^l-\Gamma_{jk}^l\delta_l^j =0$$
Thus:

$$g^{ij}\partial_k\ g_{ij}-\Gamma_{ik}^l-\Gamma_{jk}^l=0$$
Since $\Gamma_{ik}^i=\Gamma_{jk}^j$ we have :
$$ g^{ij}\ \partial_k\ g_{ij}=2\Gamma_{ik}^i$$
Let $g$ be the determinant of $g_{ij}$ we obtain :
$$\partial_k g=g\ g_{ij}\ \partial_k\ g_{ij}$$
Thus :
$$\Gamma_{ik}^l=\frac{1}{2g} \partial_k \ g=\frac{1}{\sqrt{|g|}}\partial_k \sqrt{|g|}$$
Applying it we obtain:
$$\mathbf{div \ V}=\partial_iv^i+\frac{v^i}{\sqrt{|g|}}\partial_i \sqrt{|g|}$$

> Recall : $$\frac{1}{a} d(ba)=db+\frac{b}{a} da$$
>   Let $a=\sqrt{|g|}$ , $b=v^i$

finally we have :
$$\fbox{$\mathbf{div \ V}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{|g|}} \partial_i\biggr( v^i \sqrt{|g|}\biggl)$}$$

Using this result in your main problem we get :
$$\mathbf{div \ A}=\partial_i A^i +\frac{A^i}{\sqrt{|g|}}\partial_i \sqrt{|g|}$$
I think I would let you continue. Good luck !

Comment: Thanks for your answer I found it more useful !!

Comment: You are welcome ! the tip to get the final answer is to take : $r=x^1, \theta=x^2, \varphi=x^3$

Comment: Yes, You mentioned it before, thanks again.

Comment: How did you get the line after where you write “ Let 
 be the determinant of   we obtain :”.....

Answer (score 0):

Minkowski metric$(-+++) (\eta_{\mu\nu} =\eta^{\mu\nu})$ in spherical coordinates is:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-1&0&0&0
\\0&1&0&0
\\0&0&r^2&0
\\0&0&0&r^2\sin^2(\theta)
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{1}
$$
And Christoffel symbols are defined as
$$
\Gamma^\alpha_{\beta\gamma} = \frac{1}{2}g^{\delta\alpha}(g_{\beta\delta,\gamma}+g_{\gamma\delta,\beta}-g_{\beta\gamma,\delta}) \tag{2}
$$
This is much easier in  minkowski space as only the diagonals of the metric are non-zero.

This should allow you enough information to calculate the divergence in spherical coordinates from your covariant derivative to get the proof you require.